# AngularJS directive to focus in an input field: why is the call to setTimeout needed to make it work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have defined an angularjs directive, whose purpose is automatically triggering the focus on an `input` HTML element.

The code for the directive is the following:

```
function autoFocus() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch($attrs.autoFocus, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (!newValue) {
                    return;
                }

                const element = $element[0];
                setTimeout(function() {
                    element.focus();
                }, 0);
            });
        }
    };
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('autoFocus', autoFocus);
```

This is an example of usage:

```
<input 
      ng-show="isEditMode" 
      ng-model="item.title"
      ng-blur="todo.updateTodo(item, $index); isEditMode = false;"
      auto-focus="isEditMode">
```

If I remove the call to `setTimeout` from the callback code the directive does not work as expected (the focus event is not triggered as I would expect).

Can anyone explain me why the call to `setTimeout` is needed in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common directive problem, `link` function runs before the DOM has finished rendering, so the `element` has not yet a value. The simplest (and probably cleanest) solution is the usage of `$timeout` that triggers a new digest cycle and ensures that the DOM has rendered.

(You should replace `setTimeout` with angular's `$timeout` service)

Comment: thanks. The point that I was missing is the fact that the link function runs **before** the DOM has finished rendering. So, basically, when the callback function is being executed the `element` object exists as a DOM element (as a javascript object it is actually defined), but it has not been rendered yet, correct ?

Comment: This is not the default behavior of the `link` function. It usually happens when directive elements take some time to render (templateUrl used for the html or `ng-repeat` etc is used )